# Java - Special URLs characters

Tags: java

I have a function:

```
public static ImageIcon GetIconImageFromResource(String path){
    URL url = ARMMain.class.getResource(path);
return new ImageIcon(url);
}
```

It works great, but if I place my .JAR file onto for example **C:\Ares!!!\myfile.jar** it fails and I don't see my icons. I've observed that my URL is **file:/C:/Ares!!!/myfile.jar!/com/test/images/img.png**. So after JAR extension there is the **!** symbol! I think this is the main reason! What can I do to avoid this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You should use relative paths instead of static absolute paths.

Comment: If it isn't difficult for you could you explain me how? I have standart **ARMMain.class.getResource(path)** function which returns the URL.

Comment: Instead of using `C:/XYZ/...` use relative path as `images/img.png`.

Comment: GetIconImageFromResource("images/img.png") - I do the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: can you bundle the images outside of the JAR ? i typically keep them outside and just use images/img.png.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I have to keep it within the JAR file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently a problem (more than a bug) of Java. The JAR URL uses `!/` as delimiter, but does not escape it when it appears inside the file path.

You can try to escape it yourself, turn `Ares!!!/` into `Ares!!%21/`, but keep `myfile.jar!/` as is.

---

According to RFC3986, `!` is a reserved sub-delimiter char. Therefore it's safe to use it to separate different parts in a URL; when it appears inside a part, it must be escaped as `%21`

However, Java code dealing with JAR URL apparently follows the older RFC2396, in which `!` was an unreserved char. It was unwise for Java to choose an unreserved char as separator. And when it did, it should at least internally escape it as if the char is reserved.

Comment: As I can see It's big problem for all users and programmers... So thank you all for discussion. I'm going to close this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class.